# Connecting Washing Machine Outlet Box to copper

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

I've done a search and nothing particularly relevant came up so...

I'm in the process of moving the washer and dryer in our new house and trying to figure out how to mate the valves in the connection box to the copper lines. I have a box similar to this where the values are attached via a single shut off:

[image: Connectors]

http://www.lowes.com/pd_596141-138-38568___?productId=50163629&pl=1&Ntt=washer+box

The ends are threaded, so I guess I just need to add a 1/2" to female threaded fitting like this?

[image: Threaded]

I don't currently have the part sitting in front of me, but I don't recall the male threads being turnable to screw into the fitting (I'll have to double check). Is there a trick to it, or do you screw it in and then sweat it? But that seems like a terrible idea given that its right near the plastic enclosure.

Comment: The product description says that it's a sweat connection.  So you'll  have to solder the pipes to the valve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at the valve inlets, they are designed with a 1/2" male iron pipe thread (MPT) for a threaded connection, **OR** you can solder 1/2" copper pipe *directly to the inside of the threaded fitting. It's made to accomodate either method*.

You do not need any additional fittings.

You need to be careful though, there are o-rings and teflon seals inside the valve that can be damaged by the heat from soldering. You need to take it apart by removing the large screws next to the handle, solder the included fittings, then reassemble.

See this [schematic.](http://media.wattswater.com/ES-2-M2.pdf)

Comment: You'd think they would put something like that in the box with the instructions. That makes way more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Jimmy and Tester, this box has both threaded and sweat connections.

To answer the more general question of sweating threaded adaptors:

Typical when sweating thread adaptors, you sweat the adaptor onto the pipe first, then complete the threaded connection, and lastly sweat the opposite joint at the other end. In situations were the opposite joint is too close to the threaded connection, you wrap a wet cloth around the threaded connection to help absorb the heat.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to attach (sweat) a copper pipe union (picture below) to the female threaded fitting (pictured in your question). The other end of the union would be sweated to the lines in the house. This will allow you to screw the entire assembly together (and take it apart if necessary- like for replacing the valves).

Of course you will need two copper pipe unions and two female threaded fittings; one for the hot and one for the cold.

[image]